# Series where a forest spirit is fighting an infestation by an alien parasite

Tags: story-identification, aliens

All I can remember is that in the last book the group of companions land on a new continent where they meet a forest spirit who has been fighting an alien parasite trying to infest the world.

They must travel beyond a huge mountain range so high even birds cannot pass; they do so by traveling inside a vast root the forest has grown under the mountains. However the mountains resent the intrusion and try to crush the root.

On reaching the other side they find the parasite has anchored itself to their world by latching onto one of the roots fighting it and is slowly pulling itself closer to the planet.

I read it in the 1990s.

Comment: The travel through/on a root through the ground reminds me of the Rhapsody books. Rhapsody needs ro flee and by accident meet two others who open the secret door to the roots od Sagia, the world-tree, connecring continents and times. The three fight F'dor, demon of fire, coming from outer space to the earth... [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhapsody:_Child_of_Blood)